# C++ WinApi project access issue

Tags: installation, directory, project

I have a C++ WinApi project which works fine in VS (Debug and Release) , the application writes some data in a text file start.txt and copies some images to a directory "bitmaps" , both the text file and the directory are located in the Application's main Directory, but when I install the application with a setup program in C:\Program Files (x86)\ or in C:\Program Files\ , both the text file start.txt and the folder "bitmaps" become read only , not accessible for the application to store data in them, so the application does not function correctly and some error show like:

((cimg::fopen(): failed to open file 'C:\Program Files\application Name\bitmaps\user1.bmp with mode 'wb'))
this is understood because there are no images in the directory, I checked also the text file start.txt also empty

I have read somewhere that Windows System does not allow writing data in the "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" directories and data should be written in AppData or somewhere else by applications

by the way , the application does run correctly if I run it as administrator

is there a way to set permission to the directory and the text file to make them accessible (writable) for the application to store data into without running the application as administrator after installing it?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this is to store data where they should be for example in the AppData , the problem then will be solved

to get the path of AppData folder :

```
Appdatapath= getenv("appdata"); // geting AppData path
Appdatapath +=("\\yourappData"); // adding a new directory for your 
                                // application where data are written
```